# Forward traffic from one WAN port to the other WAN port on the same triple WAN port router

Tags: ip-address, wan, static

So here's the situation that I have at my workplace (local municipality):

I have received from my ISP a static IP address with a provided gateway, which all works normally when I input it into my router (ISP's router works in bridge mode).
10.11.206.38 - host ip
10.11.206.37 - Gateway

So this works on my router, the issue I am having is that I have another 4 routers which should sit downstream of this main router on a switch connected to my main router.

For those 4 routers I've been given a range of static IP address' in a different subnet without any gateway provided (like below):
10.11.223.193 - 10.11.223.206

I have a triple WAN TP LINK Omada ER605 router to which I have connected my ISP's router on WAN1 with the host IP and Gateway provided and that connection works.

Now what I've tried is connecting one of the downstream routers to the WAN/LAN2 port which I've setup to work as a WAN port with an IP address of 10.11.223.193. I tried using the same gateway as the main router with setting different kinds of static routers to try and make my downstream router 'see' outside and see my main router from it.

But I am not not sure how to make these downstream routers connect to the outside with them having no gateway provided, can they used the gateway on different subnet (like the main router's gateway)?

I've been told by the ISP technician that if I setup this port with the first port they gave me from the range (10.11.223.193), then setup my routers with static IPs in the range I should get a connection out, but I am not clear what is the gateway for these routers?

Any help is much appreciated, I apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using the same gateway as the main router with setting different kinds of static routers to try and make my downstream router 'see' outside and see my main router from it.

That's not how it works. Any gateway used for a route needs to be "on link" = connected to the same network as the router. You cannot use a 'remote' gateway behind another router.

If you chain routers A-B-C-WAN, A uses B as default gateway, B uses C as default gateway and C uses your ISP as default gateway. Of course, each router also requires (static) routes to the downstream networks.

Note that for a device to be on topic here the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, see the [help center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We cannot provide specific help for your TP-Link gear.

Comment: One more question I only mention my router since the ISP tech told me I must have a dualwan router to make this work, isn't in this case then LAN port used on the main router to chain the downstream networks with the ISP. Because even when I try to use the main router as my gateway for the downstream router I cannot connect outside by using the WAN2 port to connect the downstream router to my main one.

Comment: On most business-grade routers "LAN" and "WAN" are just predefined port roles that you can configure any which way. You need to make sure that you source-NAT private IPv4 addresses on the ISP uplink but route transparently inside your private network.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the situation, your ISP has provided you one network (likely 10.11.206.36/30) with 10.11.206.38 as your router (host) IP address, 10.11.206.37 as gateway, and subnet mask 255.255.255.252 and that is the whole usable network.

They have then routed an additional network of IP addresses (10.11.223.193 - 10.11.223.206 which is likely to actually be 10.11.223.192/28) to your assigned host IP address (10.11.206.38). This means their network is configured to deliver any traffic for your second network of IP addresses to your host IP and to assume that your device will know what to do with traffic destined to any IP in the second network.

This means your primary router needs to be configured to 'route' traffic for those IP addresses to another device or devices. You can configure your networks between your primary router and additional routers as you desire. You can use small transit networks on links between the routers (a /31 or /30 network to accommodate a single point-to-point link between the routers) or simply subnet the given secondary network to directly connect the additional routers (as described below). How you do this on a consumer/small office router like that TP-Link is up to you to discover, it may not be possible.

The ISP was likely assuming that by telling you that you need a 'Dual WAN' router, you would get something more capable that can not only do Dual WAN but also the required routing or firewalling needed to use those additional IP addresses. With the right equipment, your setup is fairly trivial but I'm not sure it is possible with the equipment you have.

You need to make your main router act as a kind of 'hub' router to connect and route traffic to the additional routers you mention. The main WAN configuration of the primary router would remain unchanged but you need to disable NAT for traffic being forwareded to the other routers, otherwise they will have their traffic mangled/modified by the primary router. You also need to setup the 'transit' links between the primary router and the additional ones. Since you only have the small secondary network, we can assume that the additional routers will perform NAT for their LAN devices so there is no need to do any additional static or dynamic route configuration beyond the configuration of the interfaces on the primary router.

The primary router needs a WAN interface connected to the ISP as you have now (10.11.206.38).

The primary router then needs to have NAT disabled, at least for the interfaces and/or traffic for the network you want to setup.

You then need to configure four additional interfaces on the primary router, each with a /30 network. The first additional interface would have 10.11.223.193 and subnet mask 255.255.255.252, second interface would have IP address 10.11.223.197 and subnet mask 255.255.255.252, third interface would have IP address 10.11.223.201 and subnet mask 255.255.255.252, interface would have IP address 10.11.223.205 and subnet mask 255.255.255.252.

The 4 secondary routers would use IP addresses 10.11.223.194, 10.11.223.198, 10.11.223.202, and 10.11.223.206 for their WAN interfaces.

If the main router cannot provide 4 additional routed interfaces, you may need to simply configure the LAN interface as 10.11.223.193 with subnet mask 255.255.255.240 and connect all the 4 routers as LAN devices. Disable the firewall and NAT features on the main router and hope that things work. The 4 secondary routers could use IP addresses 10.11.223.194-206 with the same 255.255.255.240 subnet mask. The downside to this design is less segmentation of the networks which may or may not be desireable depending on your needs.